# how to remove specific word from id3 tag

Tags: tags, mp3, id3

i am using php id3 tag editor , my question is that can i remove only specific word from all tags. there is a word in each tag of the mp3 file like a song have tags following:

```
title= example -music.com
artist= example -music.com
```

etc,

so can i remove Music.Com from a specific .mp 3 file.
please help me to get out of this.
i want to remove only specific word not whole tag.

i also used getid3 function but there also i am not able to remove the tag

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you a php solution.

The most easy solution is the windows id3 tagger [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html).

First, load your song(s) which you want to modify.
You will find a Tag to Tag converter (ALT-5).

Then you choose the id3 tag to change. In your case the field
TITLE
with the format string

```
$repl(%title%, -music.com,)
```

and in a further step the field
ARTIST
with the format string

```
$repl(%artist%, -music.com,)
```

This will replace the part ' -music.com' of the content in your TITLE (and then ARTIST) id3 tag with nothing.

Comment: thanks but, i need a solution in php................ thankyou very much for helping me